# Binding Ellipse Fill property in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to add a colored Ellipse in a Combobox , when I add this code:

```
<ComboBox Width="300" BorderBrush="#6593CF" Visibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1"  Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Label Content="Code" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding reference}" Margin="0" Padding="0"></Label>
                <Label Content="  R " Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding R}" Margin="0" Padding="0"></Label>

                <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="Red" Margin="0"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

it works and shows the Red ellipse ; but when I bind the Fill property of the Ellipse like this:

```
<Ellipse Name="elli" Height="20" Width="20" Fill="{Binding color}" Margin="0"/>
```

and add the color property in the ViewModel, it doesn't work and shows an empty space in the comboBox.

Here is the property code in the ViewModel:

```
public string _color = "Red";
public string color
{
    get
    {
        return _color;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_color == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _color = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("color");
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the Ellipse inside a Datagrid element and yet I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ItemTemplate, the DataContext is the combobox item. That means that `{Binding color}` looks for a property named `color` on the combobox item.

`color` is a property of your main viewmodel, I gather. But each object in `Parts` is displayed using that DataTemplate. If those objects don't each have a property named `color`, you're binding to nothing. The same principle applies in a DataGrid cell template.

So you need to find the main viewmodel. If you're in a Window, that's probably the Window's viewmodel, which will be the containing control's DataContext. So try this for the combobox:

```
Fill="{Binding DataContext.color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}"
```

If you've got a combobox within a DataGrid cell template, you'll want `AncestorType=ComboBox` -- keep going up the chain until you're sure you're getting a control that has the right DataContext.

I agree with Erno that it's not ideal to express a color as a string, but the string will work.

Better would be to make your viewmodel property a specialized enum type which expresses the *semantics* of whatever the color is communicating to the user: Info/Warning/Error, OnTime/Early/Delayed -- that kind of thing. And then convert that into a brush in the view with a value converter or triggers.

Comment: To avoid the confusion whether to write `AncestorType=Window` or `AncestorType=Page` you may always just use the DataContext of the parent ItemsControl, i.e. `AncestorType=ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, and the explanation is excellente, but right now i ended up with a list full of ellipse's of the same color, what i want to do is make single color corresponding to each state of the part Object . (exemple Red for defected , Green for OK etc...)  , can you tell me more about how to use the  enum Type and the value converter in this case ?  , Thank you again

Comment: @J.Doe Think about what I said in my answer about the objects in `Parts`: The original binding you had would work if `color` were a property of those objects. Can you define an enum type that suits your needs, and then add a property of that type to the class contained in `Parts`? Please do that and add that code to your question. Then we can work through the value converter part.